# SQL Server : Case Statement in function doesn't output correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a function to shorten the query in below

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 IS NULL 
            THEN 'Missing'
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 0 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 5 
            THEN '> 0 - <= 5'   
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 5 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 12 
            THEN '> 5 - <= 12'
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 12 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 25 
            THEN '> 12 - <=25'
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 25 
            THEN '> 25'
    END AS ARPU_GRP, 
    COUNT(*) 'Toplam Müşteri Sayısı'
FROM
    TRAIN
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 IS NULL 
            THEN 'Missing'
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 0 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 5 
            THEN '> 0 - <= 5'   
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 5 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 12 
            THEN '> 5 - <= 12'
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 12 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 25 
            THEN '> 12 - <=25'
        WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 25 
            THEN '> 25'
    END
```

OUTPUT:

```
ARPU_GRP    Toplam Müşteri Sayısı
----------------------------------
> 5 - <=12  1565
> 0 - <=5   1318
> 25        678
Missing     255
> 12 - <=25 1184
```

But when I create a function from the case statement part of the query above, output changes. Normally this function always works when I use between and method, but not with this one.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ARPU_GRP
    (@Arpu INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE 
            WHEN @Arpu IS NULL THEN 'Missing'
            WHEN @Arpu > 0 AND @Arpu <= 5 THEN '> 0 - <=5'  
            WHEN @Arpu > 5 AND @Arpu <= 12 THEN '> 5 - <=12'
            WHEN @Arpu > 12 AND @Arpu <= 25 THEN '> 12 - <=25'
            WHEN @Arpu > 25 THEN '> 25'
        END 
END
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ARPU_GRP(SUBS_ARPU_M1) AS ARPU_GRP, 
    COUNT(*) 'Toplam Müşteri Sayısı'
FROM
    TRAIN
GROUP BY 
    dbo.ARPU_GRP(SUBS_ARPU_M1)
```

Output:

```
ARPU_GRP    Toplam Müşteri Sayısı
----------------------------------
NULL        208
> 0 - <=5   1392
> 12 - <=25 1053
> 25        645
> 5 - <=12  1447
Missing     255
```

Comment: FYI, `CASE` in T-SQL is an *expression* **not** a statement. It returns a scalar value, it is not a logical control flow operator.

Comment: What's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` on your server?

Comment: Is SUBS_ARPU_M1 really an INT or could be rounding the problem? 0.1 becomes 0 and 0 has no CASE for it.

Comment: I suspect the same as @Turo for why. I suspect `SUBS_ARPU_M1` isn't an `int` and hence you are truncating the value. Then would mean that a value like `0.1` would return `NULL` in your function, but `'> 0 - <=5'` in your original case expression.

Comment: I've figured out that SUBS_ARPU_M1 isn't and int. It's a float value. Now, i solved the problem. It's been just 2 months since i started that's why sometimes i can make little mistakes. Thanks a lot guys!!

Comment: `RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)` This is just lazy coding. Your function can never return anything of this size.

Comment: @SMor At least this nvarchar(max) contains characters; I've seen numerous cases, when it contains date...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a derived table?

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CASE WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 IS NULL THEN 'Missing'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 0
                 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 5 THEN '> 0 - <=5'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 5
                 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 12 THEN '> 5 - <=12'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 12
                 AND SUBS_ARPU_M1 <= 25 THEN '> 12 - <=25'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 25 THEN '> 25'
           END AS ARPU_GRP,
           YourIDColumn
    FROM dbo.TRAIN)
SELECT ARPU_GRP,
       COUNT(YourIDColumn) AS [ToplamMüşteriSayısı] --Don't use literal strings for aliases
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ARPU_GRP;
```

You can, however, make your `CASE` expression even more succinct by reversing the order of the boolean expressions and just checking the value is greater than the target:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CASE WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 25 THEN '> 25'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 12 THEN '> 25 - <= 25'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 5 THEN '> 5 - <= 12'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 0 THEN '> 0 - <=5'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 IS NULL THEN 'Missing'
           END AS ARPU_GRP,        
           YourIDColumn
    FROM dbo.TRAIN)
SELECT ARPU_GRP,
       COUNT(YourIDColumn) AS [ToplamMüşteriSayısı] --Don't use literal strings for aliases
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ARPU_GRP;
```

Comment: I know this is also another method but the company want me to do on this way.

Comment: And what was the reason the company gave for forcing you to do it that way, @BerkDeğerli ? Company "reasons" are often ill-informed.

Comment: By the way the second query is what i was looking for. I think the problem was because of  ranging with 'AND'. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Im a junior consultant and theyre giving me case studies to improve myself. Thats the reason theyre forcing me.

Comment: by the way CASE WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 25 THEN '> 25'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 12 THEN '> 25 - <= 25'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 5 THEN '> 5 - <= 12'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 0 THEN '> 0 - <=5'
                WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 IS NULL THEN 'Missing'
           END 
this is also not woring in function. Is there any way ı can get true ouput with function?

Comment: You'll need to create a [mre] @BerkDeğerli , but I suspect for the reason in the comments; you are truncating your values.

Comment: You're totally right. If it was a normal project i would do it with the easiest way. But they don't want this solution. That's the problem.

Comment: @BerkDeğerli Scalar functions are notorious for performance problems. A company that is teaching this as a form of self-improvement is doing everyone a dis-service.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want this as a function, I'd advise you to make this an ***inline* Table-valued Function** (of the form `RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT...`). It will perform far better than a scalar function. You can add it to your query using `CROSS APPLY`.

Taking [@Larnu's existing excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833209/14868997):

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ARPU_GRP
(
    @SUBS_ARPU_M1 int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT CASE WHEN @SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 25 THEN '> 25'
                WHEN @SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 12 THEN '> 25 - <= 25'
                WHEN @SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 5 THEN '> 5 - <= 12'
                WHEN @SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 0 THEN '> 0 - <=5'
                WHEN @SUBS_ARPU_M1 IS NULL THEN 'Missing'
           END AS ARPU_GRP;
GO
```

```
SELECT
  grp.ARPU_GRP,
  COUNT(tr.YourIDColumn) AS [ToplamMüşteriSayısı]
FROM dbo.TRAIN tr
CROSS APPLY dbo.ARPU_GRP(SUBS_ARPU_M1) grp
GROUP BY grp.ARPU_GRP;
```

Note that `COUNT(SomeNonNullValue)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`, so you may want to rethink that. For clarity, it will *not* count distinct values, for that you would need `COUNT(DISTINCT SomeNonNullValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Larnu's way and as you have mentioned it to do in function format then here it is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ARPU_GRP
(
@SUBS_ARPU_M1 INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    CASE WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 25 THEN '> 25'
            WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 12 THEN '> 25 - <= 25'
            WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 5 THEN '> 5 - <= 12'
            WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 > 0 THEN '> 0 - <=5'
            WHEN SUBS_ARPU_M1 IS NULL THEN 'Missing'
 END 
 END
```